# Copilot not showing suggestions in vscode yet showing input/output activity

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation

I am trying to get copilot to work with vscode.

I think the screenshot shows:

- I am logged into copilot
- copilot is sending requests to github ad getting some kind of response
- but no suggestions!
- [image: vscode screenshot]

For good measure, here is the cmd output showing I have the latest version of vscode.

[image: terminal output on install of vscode]

I have also repeatedly opened and closed vscode.

Any other suggestions?

I tried to follow various advice lines from here - [GitHub Copilot does not work after latest vscode update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831509/github-copilot-does-not-work-after-latest-vscode-update)

I was expecting to start seeing recommendations!